# Using a list from JSON in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am using a `Utilities.Cache.Insert` to insert the JSON output from a URI.

```
[
    {
    Id": 44,
    "Address": "nho:87, Huston",
    "Name": "Ann"
},
{
    "Id": 87,
    "Address": "nho:17, Texas",
    "Name": "Robert"
}
...
...
]

Utilities.Cache.Insert("my_list", AddList);
```

Then using a "SelectListItem" List to store the "Name" and "Address"

```
List<SelectListItem> d = new List<SelectListItem>();

foreach (Dictionary<string, string> item in AddList)
{
    d.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item["Name"], Value = item["Address"] });
}
```

However, I need a way to store all three values, "Name","Address" and "Id" so "selectListItem" cannot be used. What are the other alternatives?

Comment: what is Utilities.Cache.Insert ? is it a utility class you wrote?

Comment: yes it is my own.  same as system.web.caching.cache. Cache for web application